# Arduino Average library error - was not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino

Trying to run the [Average library example](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Average) on a Mega 2560 I get the following error when trying to verify:

```
#include <Average.h>
#define CNT 600
int d[CNT];

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<CNT; i++) d[i] = random(500); 
  Serial.print("Mean: ");
  Serial.print(mean(d,CNT),DEC);
}
```

Error:

```
'mean' was not declared in this scope
```

Other questions in SO deal with this error, but they seem to result from bad code whereas this is an official demo.

Comment: Where did you put the library? It needs to be in the usr/Documents/Arduino/libraries folder (or eq. for yur OS).

Comment: Ah that's it, I put it in libraries subfolder in line with Processing method. Please add comment as reply and I'll close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears to have been an issue with Arduino not being able to locate the referenced library, a common and confusing (but easy to fix!) error. For reference on how Arduino libraries should be installed, there is extensive documentation on the Arduino website: [Installing Additional Arduino Libraries](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries)